# XSLT-2.0: How to create a text file using a BASE64String?

Tags: xml, xslt, base64, xslt-2.0

I have reached a half of the way of decoding a base64string to a string using this XSLT template:

```
<xsl:call-template name="b64:decode">
  <xsl:with-param name="base64String" select="'aGVsbG9fZHVkZS1hd2Vzb21lLnJ1'"></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

> i have understood using this function we can decode base64string but

I have the following XML structure

```
<document>
  <reference>
    <text mediaType="text/plain" representation="B64">
      <reference value="Attachment For Sambar.txt" />
            aGVsbG9fZHVkZS1hd2Vzb21lLnJ1         
    </text>
</document>
```

How would I generate `.txt` files from this XML using `<reference value="Attachment For Sambar.txt">` as  a file name

Answer (score 0):

You can write a template

```
<xsl:template match="document/reference/text[@mediaType = 'text/plain' and @representation = 'B64']">
  <xsl:result-document href="reference/@value">
    <xsl:value-of select="bin:decode-string(xs:base64Binary(.))" xmlns:bin="http://expath.org/ns/binary"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```